# A Simple Linear Regression with One Neuron Gives Incorrect Results

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, regression

I am trying to code a NN with one neuron. I have one input (x) and bias (b) to solve a simple regression problem to detect x, b for the eq.: (my cost function is y=x)

y = 0.3 * x + 2.

The closest results I am getting is:

x = 0.38178107 (expected: ~0.3)

b = 1.10040842 (expected: ~1.0)

My question is why my results are far from the expected results? Am I falling into an over/underfitting problem or buffer overflow?

I took into consideration the relationship between the learning rate and the number of iterations.
I know my training data is small, but I am looping through each data entry 100 times. Also, I tried increasing the training to 100 entries and reduced the looping for each entry to 10 times, the results were much far something like x= ~3.067 and b=-3.098

Here are the steps I followed:

My training data is x: 1~10 & y:2.3~5.0. Training: [(1, 2.3), .., (10, 5.0)]

The derivatives used:

```
dE_dw = -(y-A)*x   #gradient

new_w = w - lr * dE_dw

dE_db = -(y-A) #gradient

new_b = b - lr * dE_db
```

The Code:

```
import random as r 

# function: calculate gradient for weight w for the x input or weight b for bias input
def calc_new_Weight(v, lr, grad):
  # v is value of the weight
  # lr is learning rate
  # grad is gradient 
  new_v = v - lr * grad
  return new_v

# linear cost function y=x
def costFunc(s): return s

def nn(x, y, w, b, lr):
  s = x*w + 1*b 
  A = costFunc(s)

  #Error: E = 0.5 (y - a) ** 2
  #partial deriv E w/ respect to w
  dE_dw = -1*(y-A)*x
  w_new = calc_new_Weight(w, lr, grad = dE_dw)

  # partial deriv E w/ respect to b
  dE_db = -1*(y-A)
  b_new = calc_new_Weight(b, lr, grad = dE_db)

  return (w_new, b_new)

def main():
  #random init weights w, b for the inputs x, b
  w = r.random()
  b = r.random()

  for x, y in data:
  # y = 0.3*x + 2

    for i in range(1, 100):
      #update w, b with the new weights
      w, b = nn(x, y, w, b, lr=0.001)

  print(w, b)
```

If you can help me understand this I really appreciate your time.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Isn't the expected b ~ 2?

Answer (score 0):

Your Gradients are correct but the Gradient Descent Algorithm in the code needs to be modified a little,
The Gradient Descent Algo goes like this: [reference](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-parameters-part-1-eb3e8bb9ffbb)

```
t <- 0
max_iterations <- 1000
Initialize W/theta (Weights)
while t++ < max_iterations do
    H = Forward_propogate(Inputs, W)
    delta_W = Backward_propogation(H)
    W -= n*delta_W
end
```

In python it looks like this:

```
    w, b, lr, max_iterations = r.random(), r.random(), 0.001, 1000
    for i in range(max_iterations):
        dw, db = 0, 0
        for x,y in data:
            # return dw and db from nn and not updated w and b
            dw += nn(w, b, x, y)
            db += nn(w, b, x, y)
        w = w - lr * dw
        b = b - lr * db
```

And If you want to do stochastic gradient descent(i.e update w,b for all points in the data) the code would be:

```
w, b, lr, max_iterations = r.random(), 0, 0.001, 1000
for i in range(max_iterations):
    dw, db = 0, 0
    for x,y in data:
        dw += nn(w, b, x, y)
        db += nn(w, b, x, y)
        w = w - lr * dw
        b = b - lr * db
```

Implementing SGD with your example with 50 data points and 1000 iterations and initializing random w and b to be 0 we can consistently converge to expected values:

```
import random as r 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function: calculate gradient for weight w for the x input or weight b for bias input
def calc_new_Weight(v, lr, grad):
  # v is value of the weight
  # lr is learning rate
  # grad is gradient 
  new_v = v - lr * grad
  return new_v

# linear cost function y=x
def costFunc(s): return s

def nn(x, y, w, b, lr):
  s = x*w + 1*b 
  A = costFunc(s)

  #Error: E = 0.5 (y - a) ** 2
  #partial deriv E w/ respect to w
  dE_dw = -1*(y-A)*x
  #w_new = calc_new_Weight(w, lr, grad = dE_dw)

  # partial deriv E w/ respect to b
  dE_db = -1*(y-A)
  #b_new = calc_new_Weight(b, lr, grad = dE_db)

  return (dE_dw, dE_db)

def main():
  #random init weights w, b for the inputs x, b
  w = r.random()
  b = 0

  x = list(range(1,50))
  y = [(0.3*i + 2) for i in x]
  data = list(zip(x,y))
  #r.shuffle(data)

  for i in range(1,1000):
    dw , db = 0, 0
    for x, y in data:
      # y = 0.3*x + 2
    
      #update w, b with the new weights
      d_w, d_b = nn(x, y, w, b, lr=0.001)
      dw += d_w
      db += d_b
      w = w - (0.001*d_w)
      b = b - (0.001*d_b)
    
  return w, b

w, b = main()
```